# concatenating same child tags in XML using .net

Tags: xml, vb.net

[image] [image]

Input XML File and Excepted XML file

Answer (score 0):

Use xml linq

```
Imports System.Xml
Imports System.Xml.Linq

Module Module1

    Sub Main()
        Dim input(,) As String = {{"1322274520008570", "AB"}, _
                     {"1322274520008571", "GHI"}, _
                     {"1322274520008572", "K"}
                     }

        Dim header As String = "<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""utf-8""?><FileFormatBoc></FileFormatBoc>"
        Dim doc As XDocument = XDocument.Parse(header)

        Dim fileFormatBoc As XElement = doc.Descendants("FileFormatBoc").FirstOrDefault()

        Dim len = input.Length / 2

        For row = 0 To (len - 1)
            fileFormatBoc.Add(New XElement("F", New Object() { _
                                            New XAttribute("F1", input(row, 0)), _
                                            New XElement("P1", New XAttribute("P", input(row, 1))) _
                                                         }))
        Next row

    End Sub

End Module
```

Answer (score 0):

VB.net's XML literals can use a syntax similar to WebForms to embed expressions, and uses `@` to reference attributes.  Using that and some LINQ to XML queries:

```vb
Dim xml =
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<FileFormatBoC>
    <F F1="1">
        <P1 P="A"/>
        <P1 P="B"/>
    </F>
    <F F1="2">
        <P1 P="C"/>
        <P1 P="D"/>
        <P1 P="E"/>
    </F>
    <F F1="3"/>
</FileFormatBoC>

Dim newXml =
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <FileFormatBoC>
    <%= 
        From f In xml.<FileFormatBoC>.<F>
        Select If(
            f.<P1>.Any(),
            <F F1=<%= f.@F1 %>>
                <P1 P=<%= String.Join("", From p In f.<P1> Select p.@P) %>/>
            </F>,
            f
        )
    %>
    </FileFormatBoC>
```

newXml:

```
<FileFormatBoC>
  <F F1="1">
    <P1 P="AB" />
  </F>
  <F F1="2">
    <P1 P="CDE" />
  </F>
  <F F1="3" />
</FileFormatBoC>
```